# Where has all the traffic gone?

Tags: bug

I've recently been seeing some disturbing stats for this stackexchenge, and believe them to be either false, a glitch or a problem with our subscription to google analytics.

Firstly, referring to our Area 51 Stats:

[image]

This can't possibly be correct, I know for a fact I visit the site on a daily basis, and our two erstwhile admins probably do too... and I don't believe we are alone. It also makes little sense that we have 3 visits and those 3 visitors ask 5.4 questions a day.

So I dug a little deeper and used my site analytics privilege to come across an equally baffling graph.

[image]

This is how our traffic has been distributed over the last year. It seems absolutely nobody visited this site for the first 3 months or so and we had a miracle couple of days of extraordinary activity on 8-9th of April.

Is anyone else seeing this problem? Or know the cause?